# Material icon for regular files

Tags: angular-material

I'm developing an Angular application that browses a datastore and I want the UI to look a bit like Google Drive, complete with icons next to the directory entries. What's the name of the icon Google Drive uses for regular files? It's a little blue rectangle with one corner that looks like it's been folded down.

Comment: Better description: it's like the Material "File Copy" icon without the inverted L on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! `<mat-icon>insert_drive_file</mat-icon>`. I *swear* I searched for the string "file"... :D